# Multi-column database indexes and query speed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, indexing, sqlite

I'm deploying a Rails application that aggregates coupon data from various third-party providers into a searchable database.  Searches are conducted across four fields for each coupon: headline, coupon code, description, and expiration date.

Because some of these third-party providers do a rather bad job of keeping their data sorted, and because I don't want duplicate coupons to creep into my database, I've implemented a unique compound index across those four columns.  That prevents the same coupon from being inserted into my database more than once.

Given that I'm searching against these columns (via simple `WHERE column LIKE %whatever%` matching for the time being), I want these columns to each individually benefit from the speed gains to be had by indexing them.

So here's my question: will the compound index across *all* columns provide the same searching speed gains as if I had applied an individual index to *each* column? Or will it only guarantee uniqueness among the rows?

Complicating the matter somewhat is that I'm developing in Rails, so my question pertains both to SQLite3 and MySQL (and whatever we might port over to in the future), rather than one specific RDBMS.

My guess is that the indexes *will* speed up searching across individual columns, but I really don't have enough "under the hood" database expertise to feel confident in that judgement.

Thanks for lending your expertise.

Comment: `WHERE column LIKE %whatever%` can **never** use an index; `WHERE column LIKE whatever%` can though.

Comment: @Johan: Ouch! I hadn't thought about that, though it certainly makes sense. That gives me incentive to switch over to a better search mechanism (probably Thinking Sphinx) sooner rather than later. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: before switching to Sphinx or Lucene, I'd suggest to consider MySQL fulltext search option. Might be just what you need. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @bpgergo: Yeah, I'm not committed to any particular solution right now, so I'll read up at length on the fulltext option too.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will the compound index across all
>   columns provide the same searching
>   speed gains as if I had applied an
>   individual index to each column?

Nope. The order of the columns in the index is very important. Lets suppose you have an index like this: `create unique index index_name on table_name (headline, coupon_code, description,expiration_date)`
In this case these queries will use the index

```
select * from table_name where headline = 1
select * from table_name where headline = 1 and cupon_code = 2
```

and these queries wont use the unique index:

```
select * from table_name where coupon_code = 1
select * from table_name where description = 1 and cupon_code = 2
```

So the rule is something like this. When you have multiple fields indexed together, then you have to specify the first k field to be able to use the index.

**So if you want to be able to search for *any* one of these fields then you should create on index *on each of them separately*** (besides the combined unique index)

Also, be careful with the LIKE operator.

this will use index `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Patrick%';`
and this will not `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE '%Patrick%';`

index usage http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
multiple column index http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: that's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks so much for the clear explanation and references.  I need to read up on this stuff a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: @chrisallenlane, that's exaclty the feedback I needed to get. Thanks!