# How to optimize this monster query

Tags: mysql, database

I've been wrestling with the following query (and some others similar to it) and I feel like I'm missing something or I'm using the wrong type of database or something.

The query is used to obtain the total number of new films and the total number of films that have stopped showing (closed), per year, in the UK vs a specific town, for the last 10 years. The queries are run for a lot of towns and counties also, across many years.

The other queries do similar things, sometimes adding a `UNION ALL` at the end to a query that obtains the record year for openings or closings.

There are also queries that run for monthly data and quarterly data instead of annual data, and some which just compare historical opens/closures for a particular quarter (eg Q3) or month (eg March).

Here's the query that would compare UK to London in 2012:

```
SELECT inc.opening_year as year, inc.number_of_films as opens,
    diss.number_of_films as closures, inc.uk_films as uk_opens,
    diss.uk_films as uk_closures
FROM
(SELECT film_db.opening_year, uk.number_of_films as uk_films,
        COUNT(film_db.id_film_db) as number_of_films
    FROM film_db
    JOIN postcodes ON id_postcodes = opening_postcode_id
    JOIN towns ON id_towns = town_id AND town = 'London'
    JOIN (SELECT opening_year, COUNT(film_db.id_film_db) as number_of_films
            FROM film_db
            WHERE opening_year <= 2012 AND opening_year >= (2012 - 10)
            GROUP BY opening_year
        ) uk ON uk.opening_year = film_db.opening_year
    WHERE film_db.opening_year <= 2012 AND film_db.opening_year >= (2012 - 10)
    GROUP BY film_db.opening_year
    ORDER BY film_db.opening_year DESC
) inc
JOIN
(SELECT film_db.closing_year, uk.number_of_films as uk_films,
        COUNT(film_db.id_film_db) as number_of_films
    FROM film_db
    JOIN postcodes ON id_postcodes = postcode_id
    JOIN towns ON id_towns = town_id AND town = 'London'
    JOIN (SELECT closing_year, COUNT(film_db.id_film_db) as number_of_films
            FROM film_db
            WHERE film_db.closing_year <= 2012 AND film_db.closing_year >= (2012 - 10)
            GROUP BY film_db.closing_year
        ) uk ON uk.closing_year = film_db.closing_year
    WHERE film_db.closing_year <= 2012 AND film_db.closing_year >= (2012 - 10)
    GROUP BY film_db.closing_year
    ORDER BY film_db.closing_year DESC
) diss ON diss.closing_year = inc.opening_year
```

The db `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output is follows:

**film_db:**

```
CREATE TABLE `film_db` (
  `id_film_db` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `film_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opening_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `opening_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opening_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opening_quarter` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_quarter` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `postcode_id` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `opening_postcode_id` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_film_db`),
  KEY `opening_date` (`opening_date`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `postcode_id` (`postcode_id`),
  KEY `type` (`category`),
  KEY `opening_year` (`opening_year`),
  KEY `opening_month` (`opening_month`,`opening_year`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `opening_quarter` (`opening_quarter`,`opening_year`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `closing_year` (`closing_year`),
  KEY `closing_month` (`closing_year`,`closing_month`),
  KEY `closing_quarter` (`closing_year`,`closing_quarter`),
  KEY `closing_date` (`closing_date`),
  KEY `opening_closing_date` (`opening_date`,`closing_date`),
  KEY `opening_postcode` (`opening_postcode_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `film_name` (`film_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10649173 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**postcodes:**

```
CREATE TABLE `postcodes` (
  `id_postcodes` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postcode` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `town_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float NOT NULL,
  `lng` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_postcodes`),
  UNIQUE KEY `postcode` (`postcode`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `town` (`town_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5705 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**towns:**

```
CREATE TABLE `towns` (
  `id_towns` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `town` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `county_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_towns`),
  KEY `county` (`county_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1606 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and here is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` output:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ALL                                                                                                                     11      100 
1   PRIMARY <derived4>      ALL                                                                                                                     11      100     Using where; Using join buffer
4   DERIVED <derived5>      ALL                                                                                                                     11      100     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
4   DERIVED film_db         ref     postcode_id,closing_year,closing_month,closing_quarter  closing_year    5   uk.closing_year                     2       100     Using where
4   DERIVED postcodes       eq_ref  PRIMARY,town                                            PRIMARY         4   film_db.postcode_id                 1       100 
4   DERIVED towns           eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY         4   postcodes.town_id                   1       100     Using where
5   DERIVED film_db         ALL     closing_year,closing_month,closing_quarter                                                                      9895680 47.66   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED <derived3>      ALL                                                                                                                     11      100     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED film_db         ref     opening_year,opening_postcode                           opening_year    5   uk.opening_year                     3       100     Using where
2   DERIVED postcodes       eq_ref  PRIMARY,town                                            PRIMARY         4   film_db.opening_postcode_id         1       100 
2   DERIVED towns           eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY         4   postcodes.town_id                   1       100     Using where
3   DERIVED film_db         ALL     opening_year                                                                                                    9895680 54.53   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

As you can see, MySQL doesn't think filtering on the `film_db` table will make any performance difference, so it doesn't use any keys.

**So:**

Can I improve this query to use the indexes better?

Can I improve the indexing so that the queries run faster?

Is there another database type (not MySQL) that I should be using instead for this kind of querying, where I'm mostly interested in counting the number of entries with complex conditions and joins?

Comment: what the heck is this? I suggest you to create [`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: I'm not creating an sqlfiddle with 10000000 rows in it... I've just tried to provide all the information I thought would be helpful.

Comment: just create the tables  and necessary dummy data with above query

Answer (score 1):

This is the first thing I would try:

```
CREATE TABLE opens 
SELECT opening_year, COUNT(film_db.id_film_db) as number_of_films
FROM film_db
WHERE opening_year <= 2012 AND opening_year >= (2012 - 10)
GROUP BY opening_year

CREATE TABLE closures 
SELECT closing_year, COUNT(film_db.id_film_db) as number_of_films
FROM film_db
WHERE film_db.closing_year <= 2012 AND film_db.closing_year >= (2012 - 10)
GROUP BY film_db.closing_year
```

I would use these two tables instead of the subselects you are using now.

> The other queries do similar things, sometimes adding a UNION ALL at the end to a query that obtains the record year for openings or closings.
>   There are also queries that run for monthly data and quarterly data instead of annual data, and some which just compare historical opens/closures for a particular quarter (eg Q3) or month (eg March).

I figure you run these selects more frequently then the contents of opens/closures tables would change. So it will be not necessary to rebuild these tables each time you run such a query.

---

> Can I improve this query to use the indexes better?
>   Can I improve the indexing so that the queries run faster?
>   Is there another database type (not MySQL) that I should be using instead for this kind of querying, where I'm mostly interested in counting the number of entries with complex conditions and joins?

Of course there are many other possible improvements. There certainly should be a way to have MySQL use the indexes. You should note, that the db engine cannot combine separate indexes, that is, in this case the index on `opening_postcode_id` and the index on `opening_year` cannot be combined. I can't figure why neither of them is used, but I can certainly tell that indexes like these two would improve this query

```
KEY `opening_year_postcode` (`opening_year`, `opening_postcode_id`)
KEY `closing_year_postcode` (`closing_year`, `postcode_id`)
```

see this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295744/176569

---

What I have learned over the years, this kind of performance tuning is rather a gradual process. You'll have to try more then a few tricks, evaluate the performance gain and in the end you will apply only one or two.

At this point I wouldn't consider dropping MySQL for an other database vendor. The cause of your performance problem is probably not MySQL.