# Speed of query, based on number of conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, optimization, multiple-conditions

I have a table. `specs[id,name,store_id,section_id,category_id,user_id,model_id]`
My query is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM specs
WHERE
    store_id=1
    AND
    section_id=1
    AND
    category_id=1
    AND
    user_id=1
    AND
    model_id=1
```

What I receive in result, is a list of specs.
If I will change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM specs WHERE model_id=1
```

I will get the SAME results, since the table can have duplicates (excluding the `id`, of-course)
Data sample (note that :

```
  id  |  name  |  model_id  |  section_id  |category_id  |  user_id
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   | me     | 22         | 5            |   11        |   777
  2   | you    | 22         | 5            |   11        |   777
  3   | me     | 22         | 5            |   11        |   777
  4   | me     | 22         | 5            |   11        |   777
  5   | you    | 33         | 5            |   11        |   777
  6   | they   | 33         | 5            |   11        |   777
  7   | them   | 33         | 5            |   11        |   777
  8   | we     | 33         | 5            |   11        |   777
  9   | we     | 33         | 5            |   11        |   777
  10  | them   | 44         | 5            |   11        |   776
  11  | they   | 44         | 5            |   11        |   776
  12  | me     | 44         | 5            |   11        |   776
  13  | you    | 44         | 5            |   11        |   776
  14  | they   | 44         | 5            |   11        |   776
  15  | them   | 44         | 5            |   11        |   776
```

The DB is MySQL.

The question: since the table will contain 500k-1000k records, would it be faster to use the first query or the second? more conditions will make it faster? slower?

### edit

When a record is being added, the user must supply a value for ALL columns. and the records are ALWAYS attached to a model_id.
So it doesn't really matter what other conditions are supplied, since the model is the key.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why should the result be the same using different `where` clauses?

Comment: How it can be the same? Result set will differ in common case (if not, then all your records have to be with all fields equal to 1 except `model_id` field - so why store that?). Or I misunderstood?

Comment: clarified in the original post @AlmaDoMundo

Comment: clarified .... @juergend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The result of the two query will not necessary be the same. More conditions might have less rows as a result.
2. As a general rule, you cannot say more conditions will make it faster. Under certain circumstances it is possible but not probable. It all depends on what kind of indexes you define on the table.

Here's [one of my older answer on multi-column where clauses and indexes in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295744/176569).

Comment: It would also depend on whether those conditions are sargable. Adding a like condition with a wildcard as the first character would almost certainly make it slower, for instance.

Comment: @bpgergo But it is, the results will always be the same. i will try to describe the data structure in more details.